# Autocomplete doesn't work when called as a function JQuery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Autocomplete works ok when called directly as per here:-

```
                    $('#SearchString').autocomplete({                            

                        source: function (request, response) {


                            $('#Search_EggTimer').css('display', 'inline');

                            $.ajax({
                                url: '/KnowledgeBase/Autocomplete',
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: {
                                    term: request.term,
                                    ArticleTypeId: $('#ArticleTypeId').val()
                                },
                                success: function (data) {
                                    $('#Search_EggTimer').css('display', 'none');
                                    response(data);
                                }
                            });
                        },

                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            retrieveselectedID(ui.item.value);
                            $('#SearchString').autocomplete("close");

                        },
                        focus: function (event, ui) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                    });
```

However if I try and call Autocomplete as a function it doesn't work, it just exits just before the  'source: function (request, response)' line of code and never get's called. Any suggestions?

```
        $('#SearchString').on("input", (function (event) {


                    if ($('#ArticleTypeId').val() == '5') {

                        var numero = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
                        var myArray = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
                        index = myArray.indexOf(numero);// 1
                        var longeur = $('#SearchString').val().length;
                        if (window.getSelection) {
                            text = window.getSelection().toString();
                        } if (index >= 0 & text.length > 0) {
                        } else if (index >= 0 & longeur < 10) {
                            SearchAutocomplete();
                        } else { return false; }

                    }
                    else {

                        SearchAutocomplete();
                    }

                }));

                // Autocomplete function

                function SearchAutocomplete() {            


                    $('#SearchString').autocomplete({                            

                        source: function (request, response) {


                            $('#Search_EggTimer').css('display', 'inline');

                            $.ajax({
                                url: '/KnowledgeBase/Autocomplete',
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: {
                                    term: request.term,
                                    ArticleTypeId: $('#ArticleTypeId').val()
                                },
                                success: function (data) {
                                    $('#Search_EggTimer').css('display', 'none');
                                    response(data);
                                }
                            });
                        },

                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            retrieveselectedID(ui.item.value);
                            $('#SearchString').autocomplete("close");

                        },
                        focus: function (event, ui) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: not sure what are you trying to accomplish here. when you say `Doesn't work`, what exactly not working and what do you expect?

Comment: To clarify the Autcomplete function within the SearchAutocomplete() function never gets hit. Using chrome debugger the last line of code to run is   '$('#SearchString').autocomplete.

So basically the AJAX call never happens and my search results are not returned to the SearchString input box.

Comment: Why do you need to call it as per the second piece of code that doesn't work? Which jQuery library does `autocomplete` come from?

Answer (score 0):

try to change this line, from "input" to "change":

```
$('#SearchString').on("change", (function (event) {
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. 

The code flows into the  SearchAutocomplete() function.

And hits this line after it:     $('#SearchString').autocomplete({

But then exits just before:-  source: function (request, response) {

When I look at the Chrome degugger in the console it reports:-

[Violation] 'change' handler took 6454ms

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think what's happening here is autocomplete doesn't like being a subfunction to a key event and I think therefore it loses its binding.

What I was trying to do was effectively do this:-

```
$('#SearchString').keypress(function (event) {

$('#SearchString').autocomplete({
```

I was trying to hijack the Key Event to restrict character input before it hit the autocomplete.

As a workaround I've re-written the code to validate rather then restrict the input, it's not as elegant but it works.

```
                $('#SearchString').autocomplete(
                    {
                        source: function (request, response) {

                            if ($('#ArticleTypeId').val() == '5') {

                                var input = $('#SearchString').val();
                                var numofCharacters = $('#SearchString').val().length;
                                var myArray = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
                                var index = 0;
                                var checkresult = 0;

                                while (checkresult != -1 && index < numofCharacters) {

                                    checkresult = myArray.indexOf(input.charAt(index))
                                    index++;
                                }
                                if (checkresult == -1) {

                                    alert("Please enter numerical characters only");
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }

                            $('#Search_EggTimer').css('display', 'inline');

                            $.ajax({
                                url: '/KnowledgeBase/Autocomplete',
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: {
                                    term: request.term,
                                    ArticleTypeId: $('#ArticleTypeId').val()
                                },
                                success: function (data) {
                                    $('#Search_EggTimer').css('display', 'none');
                                    response(data);
                                }
                            });
                        },

                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            retrieveselectedID(ui.item.value);
                            $('#SearchString').autocomplete("close");

                        },
                        focus: function (event, ui) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                    });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Having discussed this with a developer friend of mine I have now re-written the code but using the input restriction. This works a treat.

```
 // Check Keys entered before output to input box
                $('#SearchString').keypress(function (event) {
                    if ($('#ArticleTypeId').val() == '5') {
                        var number = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
                        var myArray = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
                        index = myArray.indexOf(number);// 1
                        if (index === -1)
                            return false;
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                // Autocomplete function 
                $('#SearchString').autocomplete(
                    {
                        source: function (request, response) {

                            $('#Search_EggTimer').css('display', 'inline');

                            $.ajax({
                                url: '/KnowledgeBase/Autocomplete',
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: {
                                    term: request.term,
                                    ArticleTypeId: $('#ArticleTypeId').val()
                                },
                                success: function (data) {
                                    $('#Search_EggTimer').css('display', 'none');
                                    response(data);
                                }
                            });
                        },

                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            retrieveselectedID(ui.item.value);
                            $('#SearchString').autocomplete("close");

                        },
                        focus: function (event, ui) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                    });
            });
```

Hope this helps anyone in the future.